# HP DL380 G6 won't automatically restart after chkdsk

Tags: windows-server-2008, chkdsk, hp-proliant

I have a DL380 G6 with a P410i RAID controller and an NC364T quad port network card. It is running Windows Server 2008 Enterprise, and is part of a SQL Server cluster.

If `chkdsk /f` is executed on the local system drive then at the end, the system doesn't restart, it just hangs at the "Windows is restarting your computer" message. If `chkdsk /f` is executed but with all (six) network cables removed it restarts fine.

We've tried replacing pretty much every component (motherboard, RAID controller, disk backplane, drives, drive bay, memory, RAID controller battery, quad port card), as well as updating all the firmware/drivers. We've also tried with individual NICs connected.

Does anyone have any idea why this might happen?

Comment: @MagicallyDelicous Thanks for the comments. I wasn't clear in the questiosn, but if I power cycle the machine it starts fine. Also, if I restart it from Windows it restarts fine. It's just restart during after chkdsk that hangs, and only if network cables are plugged in. As such, the problem is pretty minor and we've just put it down as errata. Also, there isn't a "working" machine to compare against. Sadly our cluster members aren't identical (one physical one virtual :(). Oh and vendor support didn't come up with anything.